# Error trying to add filename to end of string:

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Error trying to add filename to end of string:

```
 if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
            OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");
            cn.Open();
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filename);
            // error on this line filename only assignment, call can be used as a statement
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileuploadpath));
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

        }

    }
}

        }
```

If I try it this way:

```
        string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/");
        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fileuploadpath, filename));
```

I get a mysql error as there is no filename added to the end of the path (btw im only trying to save the path not the image) altho technically i should still be able to insert half a filepath into sql so maybe this error isnt related to my original upload method using the code above. But obviously I still need the full pathname.

The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.5.9]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''C:\Users\Garrith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite1\userdata\1\uplo' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Server.MapPath twice on the same string. Please remove it from anyone location so that the path mapped according to server may not be mapped again.

```
string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filename);
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileuploadpath));
```

You may do it like this...

```
string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + filename);
FileUploadControl.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
```

Comment: ok that helps on mapping the path but i still get an error under +filename at the end of my string fileuploadpath?

Comment: can you explain the error a bit more... what are the details of that error you are facing now?

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error as the first character in you path is ~. What you have to do is try removing this character and then save the string in your database.

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath.Substring(1,fileuploadpath.Length - 1) + "')", cn);
```

Comment: i can save ~ no problem via mysql so i dont think its that

Answer (score 0):

its ok managed to do it myself with this:

```
            //string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

        }

    }
}

        }
```